# dojox.mobile.ListItem Drag and Drop implementation with dojo

Tags: dojo, drag-and-drop, dojox.mobile

I have dojox.mobile.ListItem inside an dojox.mobile.RoundRectList got from web service. I need to implement drag and drop functionality for the list and handle that event.

Normal drag and drop in dojo is working fine with dojo.dnd.Source. But in mobile.ListItem I dont find any links. I'm not sure whether its possible or not.

It would be great if any one provide sample code or useful link regarding.

Thanks,
Siva.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the editable property on your dojox/mobile/RoundRectList and subscribe the "/dojox/mobile/deleteListItem" when removing an item.

[image]

The explanation is [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/RoundRectList.html#dojox-mobile-roundrectlist) and there are examples [here](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/mobile/tests/) under EdgeToEdgeList